# VS Code Javascript intellesense not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I cant make JavaScript autcompletions of libraries on my vscode working.

For example:

[image]

Thats what i get when i try to autocomplete axios methods, i would like to return all avaliable methods of axios for example `get`, `post` and etc...

But my VS Code just doesnt autocomplete anything.

Here is the Javascript related extensions i have installed:

- [JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next)
- [Babel Javascript](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mgmcdermott.vscode-language-babel)

What i need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED**

SOURCE:
https://codeolives.com/2019/09/18/vs-code-why-javascript-intellisense-is-not-working/

Somehow my buitin extesion "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features" was disabled, to autocompletion works this extension had to be enabled

Go to:

```
extensions sidebar tab > Filter icon > Built-in
```

Search for "typescript" and enable "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features"

This part isnt in the source i linked above, but you need it too:

Make sure you have this on your `settings.json` file:

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features",
},
```